# cakephp foreign key in multiple rows not working

Tags: cakephp

i have 2 table:

**tickets** :

```
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom_model` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_modif` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));`
```

**details**:

```
  `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `taille` enum('8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20') NOT NULL,
  `police` enum('Impact','courier new','times new roman','comic sans ms') NOT NULL,
  `bold` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `italic` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ticket_id` (`ticket_id`));`
```

the tickets have 11 **zone** (msg_acc, nom_buro,heure, date ....)
which are the attributes of fields nom in table details
and in one **zone** have (text, police, bold, italic)

therefore must save 11 rows in table (details)

i want to creat form (contains nom model in table ticket and save 11 rows in table details with foreign key ticket_id in table details is the new ticket create (nom_model) ):

I create form save 11 rows market is well but th foreing key not worked
nom_model not save in table (tickets) and the 11 rows save with ticket_id equal 0

**the code in model Ticket.php**

```
 <?php
class Ticket extends AppModel
{
   var $name = 'Ticket';
   public $displayField='id';
   public $hasMany = array(
   'Detail'
   );
}
?>
```

**the code in model Detail.php**

```
    <?php
class Detail extends AppModel{   
   var $name = 'Detail';
   public $belongsTo = array(
   'Ticket'
   );
}
?>
```

**the code in controller detailsController.php**

```
    $this->set('title_for_layout', __('Add Details'));
        $tickets= $this->Detail->Ticket->find('list');
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        if($this->Detail->saveAll($this->request->data['Detail'])){
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Model has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Model could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
              }
          $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

          }   
                $this->set('tickets', $tickets);
```

**th code in view add.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->form->create('Detail');?>
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Add New Detail</legend>
   <?php
   echo $this->form->input('Ticket.$i.nom_model');//not working
   for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
      echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.name");
      echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.text");
      echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.taille");
      echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.police");
      echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.bold");
      echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.italic");
       $this->form->hidden('ticket_id');} ?> </fieldset>
      <?php echo $this->form->end('Submit');?>
```

Comment: I can't find a solution

Comment: Note: In your view, you forgot an echo to generate the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving your request data by `saveAll` **without your associated Ticket**.

The associated data of Ticked is located in `$this->request->data['Ticket']` and will be ignored:

```
//(Line 4 of your posted controller)
$this->Detail->saveAll($this->request->data['Detail'])
```

**Update:**

Your `$this->request->data` should have the following structure:

```
Array
(
   [Ticket] => Array
                 (
                       [id] => 1
                       ...
                 )
   [Detail] => Array
                      (
                       [0] => Array
                             (                                 
                               [ticket_id] => 1
                               ...
                             )

                       [1] => Array
                             (                                  
                               [ticket_id] => 1
                               ...
                             )
                       ..........
                     )
)
```

Adapt your View, generating that datafield and you can try to save your posted data via `$this->Detail->saveAll($this->request->data)`

**Update**

Your View in basic should look like the following:

```
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Add New Detail</legend>
   <?php

   echo $this->form->input("Ticket.nom_model");
   echo $this->form->hidden("Ticket.id", array('value' => '1'));
   for($i=0;$i < $count;$i++){
      echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.name");
      echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.text");
      echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.taille");
      echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.police");
      echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.bold");
      echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.italic");
      echo $this->form->hidden("Detail.$i.ticket_id", array('value' => '1'));} ?> 
   <?php echo $this->form->end('Submit');?> 

   </fieldset>
```

This is an example view, that references `Detail` to `Ticket` via `Ticked.id = 1`

**Update:**

You should define the foreign key from `Detail` to `Ticket` in your `Models/Detail.php`:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Ticket' => array(
        'className' => 'Ticket',
        'foreignKey' => 'ticket_id'
        )
   );
```

Comment: I changed $this->Detail->saveAll($this->request->data['Detail'])

Comment: to $this->Detail->saveAll($this->request->data['Ticket'])

Comment: I have posted the datafield, your Form should generate.

Comment: In addition I have posted an example view

Comment: that's work ticket_id at value 1 but I want ticket_id at last value(exp: in table ticket i have 5 ticket donc in ticket_id must at value 5)

Comment: As mentioned, this is only an example view. You can determine your ticked_id via the controller.

Comment: i suggest to use only one for for one ticket. That´s easier for you and the users.